# How to retrieve the display name of an attribute via the Web API?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm currently pulling a contact record from Dynamics365 via Web API and within this record, there is a number of attributes e.g. marketingonly

The Logical Name is marketingonly but the DisplayName is 'Marketing Only'

My question has two parts:

1) How do I retrieve the Display Name of an attribute, given I know the Logical name?

2) Can I retrieve all the Display Names for a contact's attributes in a single call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. [Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2017/02/retrieve-metadata-using-name-in-web-api/)

> 1. How do I retrieve the Display Name of an attribute, given I know the Logical name?

```
https://<crmdev>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes(LogicalName='parentcustomerid')?$select=LogicalName,DisplayName
```

> 2. Can I retrieve all the Display Names for a contact's attributes in a single call?

```
https://<crmdev>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes?$select=LogicalName,DisplayName
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll review.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you.